# Power Automate running a DAX query but creating a CSV with different sorting from original Power BI query

Tags: power-automate

I created the following 'Run a query against a dataset' instant cloud flow, where the output from such DAX query is transferred over to a CSV table, which is saved to a Sharepoint folder, and then the flow continues on until the contents of such CSV is parsed onto a Sharepoint list.

[image]

The flow is running fine, until I realized that after making a columns sorting criteria change to the data table in Power Query, the flow still produces a CSV with the same sorting criteria prior to those changes I had just made.

To illustrate what I mean, I've put together a print where the left hand side brings the query directly out of a Power BI table (thus capturing the aforementioned changes in sorting criteria), and then after extracting the DAX code via Performance Analyzer and pasting onto the flow, I pasted the CSV resulted from such flow to the right hand side of the print (please note the query has an index column 'ID_Lanc', and the sorting criteria is performed before the insertion of such index column, which locks the order of sorting into place).

[image]

I even created a brand new flow after I changed the data table's sorting criteria in Power Query and saved the resulting CSV on a OneDrive folder, but the result produced is still the same: stuck in the old sorting criteria.

[image]

Upon investigation I'm pretty sure the culprit resides under the 'Run a query against a dataset' step, I just couldn't pinpoint exactly where by looking at the JSON code that comes out of it since I'm a newbie on all this.

Below is the DAX code placed under 'Run a query against a dataset'. I also tried running a simpler version of the code by getting rid of the '__DS0PrimaryWindowed'/TOPN piece and running only the '__DS0Core'/SUMMARIZE part of the code, and I also tried swapping SUMMARIZE with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, but yet I keep getting the same CSV output with wrong (old) sorting criteria:

```
DEFINE
    VAR __DS0Core = 
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig',
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[ID_Lanc],
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Banco/Cartão],
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Data Vencimento Fatura],
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Data],
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Descrição],
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Lançamento]
        )

    VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
        TOPN(
            100000,
            __DS0Core,
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[ID_Lanc],
            1,
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Banco/Cartão],
            1,
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Data Vencimento Fatura],
            1,
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Data],
            1,
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Descrição],
            1,
            'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Lançamento],
            1
        )

EVALUATE
    __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
    'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[ID_Lanc],
    'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Banco/Cartão],
    'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Data Vencimento Fatura],
    'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Data],
    'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Descrição],
    'Fat_CC_Lancamentos_Orig'[Lançamento]
```

I really ran out of ways of trying to solve this issue, any help on this one would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don’t have a direct answer for you in relation to the operations you’re using but this connector can sort data for you … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/

Answer (score 1):

The issue on the following link presented a somewhat similar situation:

[enter link description here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Power-BI-run-a-query-against-a-dataset-struggling-with-DAX-query/td-p/2047914)

The user there realized he switched Power BI users on the dataset and that's what was causing this problem on this query always getting an outdated version.

I then remembered that I also had switched users on my dataset, so I replicated the same dataset from scratch on a brand new dataset under the new user, and now the CSV presents a current version of the DAX query.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted solution only works if you have a handful of columns that you can manually define. I am suspecting that this happens because of empty cells in the very first row the of the returned response by the query - since it is not actually a `csv/table`, but a `JSON`, with the empty cells not included as keys. A better option if to force the Dataset Query to return `nulls`, then use the `results` field instead of the `firstTableRows`.

**1.** Turn this on:

[image]

**2.**  This is the structure of the response:

[image]

**3.** Then, in the `Create CSV Table` do not use `firstTableRows`, but a custom function:

[image]

`outputs('Run_a_query_against_a_dataset')?['body']?['results']?[0]?['tables']?[0]?['rows']`

**4.** For the headers wrapped in `[  ]` problem, I usually just purposefully name my headers into something like `XX Name XX`, then use a Compose block like this:

[image]

`replace(replace(body('Create_CSV_table'),'[XX ',''),' XX]','')`

Hope this helps! It took me ages to figure it out.